# How do I install Ubuntu onto an unformatted HDD using a Mac and a SATA-to-USB adapter without messing with the Mac's OS?

Tags: installation, hard-drive, mac

I'm planning to install the HDD in a Dell laptop. I've had a bit of trouble trying to get the bootable USB to work for me when the HDD was in the laptop. 
Thought I might have an easier go of it this way. But I cannot mess up the Mac I'm using.

Should I formart the HDD to the Mac OS? So, the Mac will be able burn the download file to the disk?

If all else, I can just go out and purchase a DVD to burn the img onto. I'm just trying to use the tools I currently have at my disposal.

Answer (score 0):

No. The Mac hardware's version of Linux is significantly different, and therefore I would instead recommend having another go at installing it on the Dell:

Redownload the Ubuntu version you wish to install

Download and install Microsoft's MD5 checker http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533

Use that to compare the checksum of the downloaded file to the checksum published at http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/DVDs/ubuntu/saucy/release/  to make sure the ISO you downloaded arrived intact.

FOR USB
Reformat the flash drive
Follow the directions at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows to download and install Pendrivelinux onto your Windows machine, and recreate your Linux booting flashdrive.
If rebooting from the LiveUSB fails, then make sure booting from USB is enabled in the Dell BIOS.
Check back here with the text of any failure messages and the model and configuration of your Dell lappie.

FOR DVD
Make sure to use a DVD-R or DVD+R not a DVD-RW or DVD+RW disc
Burn the optical disc with the Ubuntu ISO in mastering mode; don't leave it open to add files to later for that makes the disc unbootable.